# Multi User for macOS Server (Mojave)

Tags: macos, xcode

I want to allow multiple users to be able to connect to my Mac to develop with Xcode.

I’m new to macOS Server and wanted to find out what is needed to get it to work.

My internet is with FiOS.

There aren’t a lot of Mac experts in my area and the experts don’t do “house calls”. Only to commercial business.

Comment: How do you intend for the other users to connect to your Mac? Will they be connecting through other Macs? If so, hold old are these Macs and what version of macOS are they running?

Comment: They will be using Windows. I’m teaching a small group of people how to write code for iOS. These people don’t have Mac’s but wanted to get hands on experience on my Mac. I wanted to setup 1 or 2 Mac mini to allow users to connect remotely and use the Mac.

Comment: I am looking to do an in house solution like https://www.macincloud.com/pages/rdp.html